# "regular" pages not found after changing permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages, htaccess

My regular pages with the default theme can not be found, but my frontpage that is a page but it has an other theme works, even my custom post type pages work.

In my permalinks settings I have `/%postname%/`

My `.htaccess` file has this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How are you accessing the "regular" pages? From the admin menu? Might try deleting/renaming your .htaccess file in case that is buggy somehow, then revisit Permalinks Settings page in admin, which should rewrite new file if it has proper permissions (which could be the other issue).

Comment: Pages > new page and then i add i to the menu, and the permalink is the name of the page. I have done that, setting the permalink option to standard then removing the .htaccess then add /%postname&/ again. Sill dosent work..

Comment: Do you have a working URL?